# How socket send data?

Tags: c, sockets

I got a snippet from internet for send data through a socket .

Here is the code .

```
u32_t nLength = 0;
u32_t nOffset = 0;

do {
    nLength = nFullLength - nOffset;
    status = Socket->Send(((u8_t*) buff) + nOffset, &nLength);
    if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        break;
    }
    nOffset += nLength;
} while (nOffset < nFullLength);
```

My doubts are :

When `send(sock_fd, buf+bytes, buflen-bytes, flags);` function running , it will send the entire data ?

Let's assume i have a `buff` with `45 byte length` . So it will send like

```
send(buf+0, 45-0) = send(buf+0, 45);
```

So it will send complete  data with length 45 ? what is the use of length here ? initially it will 45 . Isn't ?

Comment: What is `Socket`?  What is the implementation of `Send()`?  Without those, it's impossible to be certain any answer is correct.  And are you sure this is C code?  It looks a lot like C++.

Comment: This is same as normal socket --  send(sockfd , buf , buf_len )

Comment: Why do you have a loop there? In the first iteration itself nLength becomes equal to nFullLength and entire data is sent if possible and loop exits!!

Comment: @prashanthns *In the first iteration itself nLength becomes equal to nFullLength and entire data is sent if possible and loop exits!!*  Because the entire data may not be sent.  Read the [standard for send().](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/send.html)

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes I understand. That was the reason I said "if possible". Even if you ignore the send() statement, in the first iteration nLength becomes equal to nFullLength since nOffset in initialized to 0. Thus making nOffset = nFullLength in the first iteration itself and loop will exit. So do-while loop here is not looping in any case is what i meant

Comment: @prashanthns nLength will be modified by Send() to the count of bytes  written. So nOffset will be incremented by bytes written.

Comment: @Holger Ya got it. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, no. There's no guarantee that it will send all the data you ask it to send, that's why the code looks the way it does.

The manual page for `send()` states this pretty clearly:

> Return Value
>
> On success, these calls return the number of characters sent. On error, -1 
>   is returned, and `errno` is set appropriately.

The same is true for e.g. a regular `write()` to a local file, by the way. It might never happen, but the way the interface is designed you're supposed to handle partial sends (and writes) if they do happen.

Answer (score 1):

TCP is a streaming transport.  There is no guarantee that a given `send()` operation will accept all of the bytes given to it at one time.  It depends on the available kernel buffer space, the I/O mode of the socket (blocking vs non-blocking), etc.  `send()` returns the number of bytes it actually accepted  and put into the kernel buffer for subsequent transmission.

In the code example shown, it appears that `Socket->Send()` expects `nLength` to be initially set to the total number of bytes to sent, and it will then update `nLength` with the number of bytes actually sent. The code is adjusting its `nOffset` variable accordingly, looping *just in case* `send()` returns fewer bytes than requested, so it can call `send()` as many times as it takes to send the full number of bytes.

So, for example, lets assume the kernel accepts up to 20 bytes at a time.  The loop would call `send()` 3 times:

```
send(buf+0, 45-0)   // returns 20
send(buf+20, 45-20) // returns 20
send(buf+40, 45-40) // returns 5
// done
```

This is typical coding practice for TCP programming, given the streaming nature of TCP.

Comment: Thanks @Remy Lebeau for your valuable suggestion